# Buscar un registro en mas de una tabla con campos con el mismo nombre en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola tengo dos tablas casi idénticas con los mismos nombres de campos y quisiera poder buscar un valor que pueda estar guardado en cualquiera de las dos tablas con el mismo nombre de campo. Ej:

```
Tabla: vales_personas
  campo: numero_vale
Tabla: vales_autos
  campo: numero_vale
```

Necesito hacer una consulta que me traiga todos los datos de la tabla en que se encuentra el numero de vale que necesito, sin importar en cual de las dos esté.

[image: Las dos tablas son iguales a esta]

De antemano ¡Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

- Puedes usar `UNION` para unir 2 queries.
- Ambos deben devolver la misma cantidad de columnas.

  SELECT * FROM vales_personas WHERE numero_vale = XXXX
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM vales_autos WHERE numero_vale = XXXX

Comment: Muchas gracias Manuel, me funcionó perfecto!!!

Answer (score -1):

es correcto lo que dice Manuel o si los quieres por separado puedes usar

```
Select A.numero_vale, B.numer_vale 
FROM vales_personas A, vales_autos B 
where A.id = xxxx AND A.id = B.id;
```

o  con alguna otra condición que ocupes.